# Why Shutdown menu in Ubuntu disappeared?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-panel

When I log on to the system I see Shutdown menu like this:

[alt text http://lh5.ggpht.com/_DK4gO8ys6jI/TC5gKkHYhNI/AAAAAAAABow/r-_5I5HHxC8/snapshot2.png](http://lh5.ggpht.com/_DK4gO8ys6jI/TC5gKkHYhNI/AAAAAAAABow/r-_5I5HHxC8/snapshot2.png)

but when my wife logs on to the system with her credentials **sometimes** (not always) she sees following panel:

[alt text http://lh3.ggpht.com/_DK4gO8ys6jI/TC5gK4odIYI/AAAAAAAABo0/nQaoWFlLLco/snapshot.png](http://lh3.ggpht.com/_DK4gO8ys6jI/TC5gK4odIYI/AAAAAAAABo0/nQaoWFlLLco/snapshot.png)

In this case she just press Shutdown button of the laptop and shutdown the laptop. What is wrong with her panel? How to solve this problem? Or is it some bug (I don't think so)?

I have read this question [Gnome’s shutdown menu disappeared](https://superuser.com/questions/152955/gnomes-shutdown-menu-disappeared) but I think in my case the problem is different. Because this problem happens **occasionally** not often.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The menu is still there, just its "decal" is screwed up. If you left-click the "Me menu" button with your name on it and mouse right, the "Indicator Applet Session" menu appears properly.

There was a major 10.04 UI patch bundle that went out in the last day or two, I've not seen this buglette reappear since. Just use the normal System ➤ Administration ➤ Update Manager and this may go away.

**update**: Further research shows this bug has been bouncing around Ubuntu/Gnome for nearly a year with a couple dozen bugs filed against it, poor reproducibility, and not-so-horrible effect. No one can decide whether it is the window compositor, gnome-panel, or the indicator applet session. As the "central" bug report notes

> "...Please don't confirm the bug it is
>   already confirmed. Please don't attach
>   further screenshots - we all know how
>   the problem looks..."

so you might just want to sign on as a "subscriber" to the bug report to be notified if something changes; I wouldn't hold my breath.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/439448

Comment: Thanks I will try it. Let's hope that the problem don't show itself.